# Get the exit code before disown

Tags: exit-status, timeout, disown

I am executing a command using `timeout` in the following way that waits for seconds and then exits

```
timeout -k 1 10 <command> &> error.log & disown %
```

However, I've realized that since this is a single command; it would not be possible to get the exit status code from the `timeout` command. I would like the get the exit status code from the `timeout` command to output verbose messages. I have searched this forum and was unable to figure out a solution.

Is there someway to get both the exit status code first and then disown it?

**UPDATE**:

The reason I disown is because I do not want the "Terminated message" to be displayed in the console.

```
line 106:  5777 Killed                  timeout -k 1 10 <command>
```

I want my script to terminate the command after a certain time. If the command executes in less than threshold; the script continues; else, the script is exited.

Comment: The exit status reported when starting a background task is always zero. The exit status of your command would be available to the shell that started the command if it used `wait` on the command's PID or job ID, but not until it terminates (for obvious reasons, it's the _exit_ status). Please clarify what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: updated comment!

Answer (score 1):

When a command exits and sends a code, there won't be anything left to be `disown`ed. You could try to supplement the command with something to write the exit code to disk, and then background and `disown` the entire list.

Comment: updated comment!